# TDD. Is it correct to assert about internals of the class?

Tags: java, concurrency, tdd, assertions

when implementing in tdd manner, do you assert about internals of the class or only about its public api?

lets say i'm implementing a binary heap. after adding an object I would like to assert that heap proerty is preserved. 
Do you thing that make sense to get internal array by reflection and then assert about its content?
i.e

```
    @Test
    public void shouldPreserveHeapProperty() {
        // when
        heap.push(3);
        heap.push(2);
        heap.push(1);

        // then
        assertThat(Reflection.get(heap,"elements"))).contains(3,2,1);//made up Reflection class
    }
```

or maybe by its public api? but it would require multiple assertions per test
i.e.

```
    @Test
    public void shouldPreserveHeapProperty() {
        // when
        heap.push(3);
        heap.push(2);
        heap.push(1);

        // then
        assertThat(heap.pop()).isEqualTo(3);
        assertThat(heap.pop()).isEqualTo(2);
        assertThat(heap.pop()).isEqualTo(1);
    }
```

whats more, how would you implement a test for a concurrent code? Sometimes it's really hard to simulate deadlock or waiting without accessing internal lock.

Comment: make `elements` package private, so you don't need reflection to test it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use only the API. That said, you can use package-private access to give your testing code and friendly classes limited access to some items that should nit be public.

To do this, you will discover that to test your mutator methods you will also need some getter methods to access significant properties of the object. For a stack you might need only push and pop mutators, but for testing it can be useful to have a size getter.

I find that restricting yourself this way naturally leads to a programming by contract approach, which is a good thing.

Tests that access private data are troublesome when you want to refactor your class. You should be able to easily alter the private details however you want, but instead you must also alter your test code.

Your example test tries to check that the class preserves the heap property. This is not something that one test can check. The heap property is a constraint on all sequences of push and pop. Try ceating a test case with one push followed by one pop, and another with two pushes followed by two pops. Together they act as a poor mans proof by induction that your class is correct for all sequences.

The idea that each test should contain only one assertion is quite common, but unnecessary and troublesome. When you are refactoring code, and there is the danger of introducing a bug, you want to maximise your chance of detecting those bugs. So you ought to check all the post conditions of the mutatir you are testing, and all the invariants of the class. That can be very many assertions,  so multiple assertions per test case is the only practical approach.

Comment: Asserting that two pops produce the correct two numbers might be technically two asserts but logically only one assertion. That's what is meant by "one assertion per test".